# Объясните насчёт filter_input

Tags: php, фильтрация

Не могу разобраться как работает php функция filter_input. Немного разобрался в PHP, но в документации дается тяжело.
Например, есть код

```
<?php
$example = filter_input(0, 'input');
?>
```

и форма

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="example">
</form>
```

В документации указано:

> **filter**
>   Если не указан, то используется FILTER_DEFAULT, который равнозначен FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. Это значит, что по умолчанию не применяется никакого фильтра

Теперь интересует такой вопрос, если я не указываю флаг в $example, то функция фильтрует данные или нет смысла ее использовать в такой конструкции? 
Или лучше пользоваться функциями htmlspecialchars, strip_tags и так далее

Answer (score 2):

**$_GET**, **$_POST**, **$_COOKIE** и **$_REQUEST** фильруются с использованием фильтра по умолчанию. filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input') без дополнительных параметров тоже использует фильтр по умолчанию. поэтому нет разницы. либо вы получите переменную из

```
$example = filter_input(0, 'input');
```

либо

```
$example = $_POST['input'];
```

в любом случае придется далее заниматься санитайзингом, т.е. использовать htmlspecialchars и т.д. Поэтому, наверно, есть смысл использовать filter_input с третьим параметром.